# Convert a data read in by fread function to data.frame

Tags: r, class, data.table, fread

Assume that I have a sample csv file which has 3 rows and 4 columns. Say it looks like the following:

```
name1 name2  name3 name4
11    12     13    14
21    22     23    24
31    32     33    34
```

I read it in using `fread()` (I am using the small sample for illustration purpose):

```
data <- fread(sample.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

then I do

```
class(data)
```

it will return

```
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I want to see the first element of the fourth column, I tried

```
data[1,4]
```

But it returns 4 (which I guess is the index of the column).

Interestingly, when I call the following

```
data[1,]
```

or

```
data[1]
```

it returns the first row.

So I did

```
data <- data.frame(data)
```

to convert data to a data frame.

My questions: 
1. Since the initial data has two classes, is there a way for me to choose one class and 'drop' the other? In my case, I just want to use the data as data frame.
 
2. In general, if data has more than one class, may we choose one class to keep? For instance, `as.POSIXct()` will return an object with two classes ("POSIXct" "POSIXt"). What if we just want to keep one of the classes? Any function works for this purpose in a generic way?

Comment: You can get a regular data frame with `data.table = FALSE` in `fread()`. The other functions are `class<-()`, `oldClass()`, `unclass()`, `help(class)`, etc.  But you may not want to remove the `POSIXt` from a date-time as it may produce unintended consequences

Comment: Well addressed. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, `data[1,4]` will behave as you expect in a future iteration of data.table.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use fread and want to get data as data frame just set the property of `data.table` to FALSE. By default it is true.

A `data.table` by default. A `data.frame` when argument `data.table=FALSE;`

E.g.

```
options(datatable.fread.datatable=FALSE).
```

See the documentation of R fread for reference.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/fread

Comment: Or just, as you imply but don't type out explicitly, `fread("file.csv", data.table=FALSE)`

Answer (score -2):

```
data <- read.csv(sample.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Use `read.csv()` to directly get the csv as data.frame.

If you use `data[1,4]`, you should 14 as the output.